# Use of undefined constant in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue with `siteSocialSettingsData` in my blade view I am getting

`Use of undefined constant facebook - assumed 'facebook'`

However I am confused as to why its happening as the `GeneralSettings` area/section is working how it should and they are both the same sections of code

In my function I have done `var_dump($siteSocialSettingsData->facebook);` and it works as I want it

**Function:**

```
$siteSettingsDB          = GeneralSettings::get();
$siteSettingsData        = $siteSettingsDB[0];

$siteSocialSettingsDB    = SocialSettings::get();
$siteSocialSettingsData  = $siteSocialSettingsDB[0]; 

return view('admin.pages.settings.general.general', compact('pageTitle','siteName', 'pageName', 'fullName','cpuUsage','memoryUsage', 'siteSettingsData', 'siteSocialSettingsData'));
```

**Blade:**

```
<input class="form-control updateField" data-id="facebook" data-url="{{ route('socialDataSubmit', facebook )}}" data-title="Facebook" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" type="input"  value="{{ old('facebook', $siteSocialSettingsData->facebook)}}"> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default edit" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></span>
```

Comment: `route('socialDataSubmit', facebook)` is your issue. That's PHP code, and `facebook` isn't a string or a variable, so it tries (and fails) to find a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just entering `facebook` without telling PHP if that's a variable or a string and that's why you're getting the error. The error is in your blade view, at the `data-url` attribute, when you're calling the route function (check the second parameter).

You need to change your view to:

```
<input class="form-control updateField" data-id="facebook"
    data-url="{{ route('socialDataSubmit', $siteSocialSettingsData->facebook )}}"
    data-title="Facebook" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" type="input"
    value="{{ old('facebook', $siteSocialSettingsData->facebook)}}">

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default edit" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </button>
</span>
```

Comment: I clicked as soon as I got to string what it was - thanks Milz